# xcode 3.2.2, can't see nib design view

Tags: xcode, xib

I recently updated to xcode 3.2.2 yet now when I click my .xib files, I can't see the view window where I can drag/drop stuff, I only see the inspector panes and can't get the design view to show

Comment: Is the window listed in the Window menu?

Comment: Yes, I can see the view, files owner, first responder, etc and all the views elements (labels, etc) but can't open the actual view..or I try to open it and nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-click the view in the xib object viewer (normally this would cause the view to appear and become active) and you will see the object viewer lose focus. Press CMD+W (to close the invisible view) and then double-click to open it again. It should appear on your screen now.